# How to setup input bindings for a component when it's created by router-outlet?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When a component is created by the router how can I setup property bindings?

Answer (score 5):

It is not supported to use bindings for components added by the router. 
See also this discussion https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4452

Use a shared service to communicate with components added by the router. 
For details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Well, looks like this usecase isn't solved very well.