# Displaying component with @Input in another component's router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I wanted to know if you guys know a way to display components that take a @Input directive inside of a router-outlet.

I have several components that takes in @Inputs and I would like to display these components dynamically in one component. I would like to design this one component container to be as abstract as possible, so it would be reusable and extendable in the future.

I'm trying to achieve something like

big-container.component has

```
<router-outlet name='container1'></router-outlet>
```

in which links to container1.component which contains

```
<container1 [settings]=mySettings></container1>
```

I would like to get container1.component to display in big-container.component's router-outlet with the [settings].

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup input bindings for a component when it's created by router-outlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647918/how-to-setup-input-bindings-for-a-component-when-its-created-by-router-outlet)

Comment: not quite, it doesn't seem to solve or work around for input binding. or i might be overlooking a post

Answer (score 1):

As this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34648272/7038491) states it is currently not possible.

Here is the [linked issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4452) on Github

> Use a shared service to communicate with components added by the router. For details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html